# Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: docker, mono

Could you please help me out in troubleshooting the issue:

> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

while running mono project on docker container

Scenario:

- Creating a custom docker image to run .net storm topology using Mono

My custom docker images has :

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Storm 1.1.0
- zookeeper 3.4.6
- Mono 4.8.1

Comment: Could anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: how did you install mono? can you test using Mono 5.0.x?

Comment: I followed the http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives, > apt-get install mono-complete.  Where can I find Mono 5.0 ?

Comment: see http://www.mono-project.com/news/2017/04/24/mono-linux-package-repository-changes-beginning-with-5-0/

Comment: I have this issue with Mono 5.0.1.1, too. Any idea?

Comment: Possibly related [issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/docker-fsharp/issues/24) and [PR](https://github.com/project-everest/everest/commit/e4c6591642c50c2e0c3457f1de3f56a346a91457)

Comment: Finally I could able to find an alternative :  Changed my docker image to debain:8.8 and then could able to run mono. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to change the mono TLS provider.

The default TLS provider in newer mono versions is BTLS. But you can change it to the legacy TLS provider:

Try adding `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy` to your environment variables, when you are having trouble with BTLS.

Answer (score -3):

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/#cert-sync

Mono doesn't create certificates for you.  How do they know what you want to trust?  Or do you blindly trust everything ?

`cert-sync --user` may also be useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As requested by thewaywewere:


If you want to invoke the tool manually (e.g. you installed via make install, not packages) use


cert-sync /path/to/ca-bundle.crt


On Debian systems, that’s


cert-sync /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt


and on Red Hat derivatives it’s


cert-sync /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt


Your distribution might use a different path, if it’s not derived from one of those.

Comment: @pan please add that in your answer using the [edit] link