# How to correct "Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION"

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono

I've upgraded an **Ubuntu 18.04** to **20.04 VPS**.

Then I've also upgraded **Mono runtime**, which is now **6.12.0.200**.
Apache is **2.4.41**.

I've a "mixed" application **PHP** + some web service in **Asp.net** / **ASMX**.

After the upgrade if I call any ASMX  i got the following error:

```
Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION.
```

My server runs on **HTTPS** with a let's encrypt certificate.

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can find, Mono uses a version of BoringSSL that is based on a branch of OpenSSL v1.0, and only at v1.1.1 did it begin to support TLS v1.3.  So it seems like you should be attempting to fall back to TLS v1.2 in all associated software, Apache in particular, until Mono updates their OpenSSL/BoringSSL branch.

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374000/6309), try and set `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER` tp `legacy`, to check if the issue persists, and relaunch your application.

```bash
MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy mono your_app.exe
```

[`mono/mono` issue 11763](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/11763)] mentions:

> ```bash
> export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy
> mono MonoSslTest.exe
> ```
>
> Works: `Certificate Subject [CN=client1]`
> However, using the legacy provider on this platform makes every HTTPS request take >30 seconds (even those not using a client certificate), compared to btls which otherwise works normally.
>
> In case you're not happy to wait another year, I resorted to a workaround of just not using HTTPS with Mono, and instead using nginx as a proxy and passing the client certificate to Mono in the request header.

---

> My app is a web service..it's not an app... i think it's called from apache2 daemon

If your application is a web service hosted behind Apache (likely via [mod_mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)), setting environment variables for services is a bit different than for user-run applications.

### Systemd Services (common for modern Ubuntu installations

If Apache2 is managed by `systemd` (which it usually is in Ubuntu 20.04), you can set environment variables for it by editing its service file or by using a drop-in file.

- First, find the service file:

  ```bash
  systemctl show -p FragmentPath apache2
  ```

  That command will show the path to the `apache2.service` file.
- Create a drop-in directory for the Apache2 service, and create a drop-in file to set the environment variable:

  ```bash
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/
  sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/override.conf
  ```
- Add the following content to this file:

  ```ini
  [Service]
  Environment="MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy"
  ```
- Reload the systemd configuration, and restart Apache2:

  ```bash
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl restart apache2
  ```

### SysVinit or Upstart (older systems)

If for some reason you are using SysVinit or Upstart, you would likely need to edit the Apache startup script directly (usually located in `/etc/init.d/`) and add the environment variable setting near the beginning of the script. However, this is less common in newer systems, especially Ubuntu 20.04+.

Comment: My app is a web service..it's not an app... i think it's called from apache2 daemon

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. 
Unfortunately i got again: 500 - Internal Server Error
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION
  at /build/mono-6.12.0.200/external/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.c:462

Comment: @stighy OK. What is your version of mono? (in `/etc/mono/...machine.config`). Can you  create a minimal ASP.NET app that only serves one page over HTTPS and see if you get the same error? You could also consider a different server, like [Caddyserver](https://caddyserver.com/), as [mentioned here](https://community.nethserver.org/t/replace-apache-with-caddy/17482) (with automatic Let's Encrypt support).

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.200 (tarball Tue Jul 11 21:37:50 UTC 2023)

Comment: @stighy Just for testing, would the issue persists with a downgraded Mono?

Comment: How can I downgrade Mono ? Can you help me ?

Comment: @stighy Check the versions available: `apt-cache showpkg mono-complete`? Uninstall the current one `sudo apt-get remove --purge mono-complete` + `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Install an older one: `sudo apt-get install mono-complete=<version-number>`. Pin that version: `sudo apt-mark hold mono-complete` (later on, unpin it, for automatic update: `sudo apt-mark unhold mono-complete`). Check the version: `mono --version`.

Comment: Hi again.. using , for instance, sudo apt-get install mono-complete=5.20 or 5.18 or 5.12 etc, it return : Version '5.20' for 'mono-complete' was not found ..
So , can you help me add repository that contains older mono versions ?
Thanks

Comment: @stighy After `remove` and `automremove`, try `sudo apt-key del 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF` + `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official*.list`. Then `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF` (as [shown here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259808)) and `echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic/snapshots/5.20 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list` (Replace `5.20` with the version you wish to install).

Comment: @stighy Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`. To check `mono --version`.

Comment: Downgrade Mono is impossible... I give up

Comment: @stighy I am sorry this is not working. Hopefully, your bounty will attract other answers.